# don't have permission on file copied another account

Tags: internet

I copied some of the folders from another account to the administrator account using gksu. Now, I am not able cut or delete that file and also not able to set permission.
help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions to "777" using the root user should work. The following commands will set these files to be open and usable by anyone.

WARNING: Any account can use these files after the following commands have been executed. This should not ever be applied to system files or directories!

```
sudo chmod 777 <your filename>
```

No brackets should remain...

And for folders you can use the following:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 </full/path/to/your/directory/>
```

Another example is to change so that you are the owner of the file:

```
chown [owner]:[group] <your filename>
```

To read more about permissions read the following articles:

[chmod](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/), [chown](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-change-ownership-file-linux)